# Is there any way to launch outlook, and switch to calendar view with html(or javascript)?

Tags: browser, outlook

as title. Is there possible to have a link with such function?

Something like deeplink?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for your reference.

1. I tried to start Outlook showing my Calendar by using UI way. Like this: 
   [Start Outlook showing my Calendar, Contacts, or Tasks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/start-outlook-showing-my-calendar-contacts-or-tasks-22f2ff3a-5417-47e8-b94d-b4a4b33337d2?omkt=en-001&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)

So can we find any way to use the code to setting the "Outlook start and exit" option? Registry or PowerShell ? I' not sure for this.

2. Create A Desktop Shortcut For Outlook Calendar, then using the code to start the Shortcut. Related link: 
   [How To Create A Desktop Shortcut For Outlook Calendar/Specific Folder?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3933-desktop-shortcut-for-outlook-calendar.html)

Here some links:

[How to start Outlook 16 so folder navigation shortcuts pane shows](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-start-outlook-16-so-folder-navigation/4ff58ea2-e061-438a-9fa2-79888bb646d8)

[Use a macro to open the Calendar to appointment date](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/macro-open-calendar-appointment-date/)